# Disabling edit text OnLongClick options popup

Tags: android, android-edittext

How do you disable the `OnLongClick` event on an edit text?

I did try the following things:

```
editText.cancelLongPress();
```

also

```
editText.setOnLongClickListener(null);
```

and also the

```
editText.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But nothing worked. Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if it can help you :

```
         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:longClickable="false" />
```